# Is there any way to change the title and save type of file dialog on electron?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron

I've created a button for downloading and saving a file returned from an api endpoint.

In common browser, after clicking the button, a save file dialog appears with title `Save As` and `Save as type` displayed by file's extension. But in `electron`, the title seems to be a file url (in my case it shows `blob://https:...` cause mine is created with `URL.createObjectURl`).

So is that any options I need to set to `a` tag to make the dialog title is `Save As` and correct the save type of file (without using native dialog of electron)?

```html
...
<a hidden href='/' ref={downloadRef}>download</a>
<button onClick={handleSaveFile}>download</button>
...
```

```js
const handleSaveFiles = (file: Blob, fileName: string): void => {
  const fileDownloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  if (downloadRef.current) {
    downloadRef.current.href = fileDownloadUrl;
    downloadRef.current.download = fileName;
    downloadRef.current.click();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the dialog opened when clicking that button already is electron's dialog, then I could edit the title and filters by `will-download` event.

```js
...
this.browserWindow = new BrowserWindow(option);
...
this.browserWindow.webContents.session.on('will-download', (event, item) => {
 let filters = [];
 switch (item.getMimeType()) {
  case 'text/csv':
   filters = [{ name: 'Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File', extensions: ['csv'] }];
   break;
  case 'application/octet-stream':
   filters = [{ name: 'Zip archive', extensions: ['zip'] }];
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }

 item.setSaveDialogOptions({
   title: 'Save As',
   filters: [...filters, { name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*'] }],
 });
});
```

Refer to https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/download-item#downloaditemsetsavedialogoptionsoptions